# How to add delay after promise.all in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have eg: 20 (can be dynamic) promises which makes API call. I am dividing into batches of 10. like `[[p1,... p10], [p11,... p20] ...]`

I am having for loop on it and executing p1 to p10 promises using `promise.all` like that then p11 to p20 etc..

```
 let res: any = [];
 batch.forEach(item => {
     Promise.all(item).then(values => {
        res = [...res, ...values];
     });
 })
```

Now Here I want to add delay between `p1..p10` to `p11..p20`. What is the way for this in Javascript ?

Comment: `.forEach` isn't promise-aware; just write a regular `for` loop and `await` each batch, then you can easily pause in-between.

Comment: May be wrap it within the setTimeout and add the timing as per the index of the batch.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function timeOut(delay) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), delay))
}

async function wrapper() {
  let res: any = [];
  for(let item of batch) {
    const values = await Promise.all(item)
    res.push(...values);
    await timeOut(2000)
  }
}

wrapper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a Array.forEach method you can't `await` promises so the best approach is to use a common `for...of` loop.

Here i declared a sleep function to implement the delay and then i just wrote your logic but using a normal loop

```js
const sleep = async sec => new Promise((resolve, _reject) => setTimeout(resolve, sec * 1000))

;(async () => {
    let res: any = [];
    for(const item of batch) {
        const values = await Promise.all(item);
        res.push(...values)
        await sleep(2) // n of seconds you want
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a serial execution with `wait`, you can follow below using `reduce` with serial promise chaining.

```
const wait = (timer) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timer * 1000));

let res: any = [];
batch.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // chain last item promise in loop
  return acc.then(() => 
    Promise.all(item).then(values => {
      res = [...res, ...values];
    })
    // one items promise resolved wait 10sec
    .then(() => wait(10))
  );
}, Promise.resolve());
```